# A TRAC-Like software

Tags: php, svn, project-management, trac

I tried TRAC before and knew how powerful it is
But I'm having lots of difficulties to to put it on an online host, it needs lots of resources and can't put it on a regular paid host

So I wanted to know if there is a TRAC-Like but written with PHP or something, I need it to have SVN, Wiki, Ticket issuing and maybe Forums

Comment: There is a good list of commercial Trac hosting services here: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CommercialServices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) (RoR)
- [Retrospectiva](http://retrospectiva.org/) (RoR)
- [jotBug](http://code.google.com/p/jotbug/) (PHP + Zend)
- [FusionForge](http://www.fusionforge.org/) (PHP)

Comment: +1 for retrospectiva, I hadn't heard of them and the Agile plugin looks very, very promissing.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Ruby on Rails support, you might take a look at [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/).  It has all of the features that you require.  I've recently started using it and have been pretty happy with it.  I was never able to find one written in PHP that suited my needs.

Comment: Yes, I do have
and this one Looks great
will try it and see

Comment: From what I saw researching it, the svn support is pretty nice too.  But I use git and cvs, so I couldn't tell you from experience.

Comment: It has CVS integration. I think git as well?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [InDefero](http://projects.ceondo.com/p/indefero/)? It's written in PHP and tries to be a clone of Google code. It has support for git, svn and Mercurial.

Comment: Indefero is a pain to host on most shared and even dedicated hosting, as the way it is coded is not compatible with all configs. We have to manually do permission changes etc... what a pain..

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [InDefero](http://www.indefero.net) too. Clean and fast.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have same issue, but I badly *wanted* Trac and nothing else. I finally rented a small Windows-based virtual server at €20/month (the linux ones are cheaper) on which I do all my development stuff: Subversion, a test Apache environment, and Trac. It takes some time to set up, but I'm quite happy with it and can recommend it. Also, on standard shared hosting, your problems might not end with Trac: Subversion is a rarity among hosting providers as well. Depending on where you are based, e.g. 1and1 rent cheap virtual servers in europe and the US.